# Enable rewrite to internal sub folder and add slashes to access files

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

i need to enable htaccess to rewrite the url sample bellow:

Home
http://test.com/ -> /view/template/index.php 
the RewriteBase is /view/template/ 
to rewrite any other file or directory css/ js sample

Content URL
http://test.com/post/12345 -> /view/template/post.php?id=12345

I try

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite default Theme dir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.view/assis/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post/$ /app.view/assis/post.php?id=31 [L]
```

Can you help us!

Comment: "I can't" <- why?

Comment: i need help to make this rewrite rule, tks

Comment: Check out documentation for [htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.htaccess/topics) and [mod-rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.htaccess/topics). [SO] is not "_write my code for me_" website. You have to show your attempts.

Comment: RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite default Theme dir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.view/assis/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post/$ /app.view/assis/post.php?id=31 [L]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the following rule is useful at all:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
```

As to the question, try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /app.view/template/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^post/(\d+)/?$ /view/template/post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The rewrite to post file its OK but not working to index file. I need to make a rewrite base to /app.view/template/index.php . Tks